# Repeatedly emitting values from a growing array

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Quick context: I'm displaying a "live" image slideshow, meaning as images are being displayed, users can upload images & those new images should display (eventually). This is "infinite", meaning I want to restart at the first image once all images have been emitted. New incoming images should go to the end of the queue & emit once I loop back to them.

I've come up with what I think is a dirty & incorrect solution that boils down to:

```js
const srcArray = [-2, -1];
const userImageUpload$ = interval(2000).pipe(
  tap((val) => srcArray.push(val))
).subscribe();

const liveImages$ = zip(interval(1000), from(srcArray)).pipe(
  map(([a, b]) => b),
  repeat()
).subscribe((val) => console.log("Image " + val));
```

Here we have a starting array of some "images". The `userImageUpload$` represents the idea of new images incoming. When I get one I push it into the starting array. `liveImages$` represents the values I want emitted. This technically works, but altering this shared global array feels bad and may lead to issues. Is there a good solution to do this all in one, possibly with the use of subjects? I'm having trouble coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep a `currentImages$` observable which accumulates all the uploaded images, and a `currentImageIndex$` observable which keeps the index of the image which should be currently displayed.
Then the `liveImages` Observable (which combines the two) is the result you want.

```
const currentImages$ = userImageUpload$.pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], [])
);

const currentImageIndex$ = interval(SLIDE_SHOW_INTERVAL).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(currentImages$),
    map(([, currImages]) => currImages),
    scan((accIndex, currImagesArr) => (accIndex + 1) % currImagesArr.length, 0)
);

const liveImages$ = currentImageIndex$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(currentImages$),
    map(([currIndex, currImages]) => currImages[currIndex])
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, solves the problem well. Haven't used scan before, but after studying this it seems great.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BehaviorSubject` makes more sense. I think your solution is fine, the difference in this answer is you get notified when the image get uploaded i.e array get updated, by start off the stream with `imageStore`.

```
const imageStore=new BehaviorSubject([-2, -1]);

const userImageUpload$ = interval(2000).pipe(
  map((val) => imageStore.getValue().concat(val))
).subscribe(imageStore);

imageStore.pipe(switchMap(srcArray=>
 zip(interval(1000), from(srcArray)).pipe(
   map(([a, b]) => b),
   repeat()
  )
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this, you can see the same in my stackblitz (Angular example)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhvt8r?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
private images: BehaviorSubject<number[]> = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([
    -2,
    -1
  ]);
  private imagesChanged$ = this.images.asObservable();

  imageToDisplay$: Observable<number>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.imageToDisplay$ = this.imagesChanged$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => interval(1000)),
      map((v: number) => v % this.images.value.length),
      map((v: number) => this.images.value[v])
    );
  }

  addImage() {
    this.images.next([
      ...this.images.value,
      this.images.value[this.images.value.length - 1] + 1
    ]);
  }
```

```
<div>
    Current Image: {{ imageToDisplay$ | async }}
</div>

<button (click)="addImage()">Add a Image</button>
```